# How to add meta tags to <head> section of all pages in GoDaddy website?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I'm trying to add Google meta verification code and Google Tag Manager (GTM) script tags to all pages of a client website. The website is created using GoDaddy Website Builder.

I couldn't locate the specific section or option to insert these meta tags. I have checked various settings and options, checked guides. I tried GoDaddy chat support and its not working.

Here is a screenshot of dashboard:

[image]

If anyone has experience with adding meta tags and scripts to a GoDaddy website, could you please point me where to add the meta tags?

Thank you in advance for your time and expertise.